# jquery validate remote function

Tags: php, jquery, validation

I'm using the validate plugin with my form and i'm facing some difficulties with the remote function.

I'm using it to ajax post to a file which in turn returns true or false.
When i enter an email that is taken or taken username, it will alert with the right error message.

But when ajax returns true, it wont do anything. That is, until i click the email inputbox, and click out to re-trigger it. then it will validate it. Ive tried alot of different solutions, like onblur triggers etc.. thing is, that all the other inputfields work out of the box, no problem. the checkmail file is very straight forward, echoing either true or false, no real issue there..

It's an e-mail check and a username check and the rules are the same for both, except the file it calls :

```
$("#registerHere").validate({
onkeyup: false,  
onblur: true,
rules:{
                    usr_name: {
                    required: true,
                     minlength: 5,
                    remote: {
                    url: "inc/checkuser2.php",
                    type: "post",
                    async: false
                                    }
                    },
                    full_name:"required",
                    blog_name:"required",

user_email: {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    remote: {
        url: "inc/checkmail.php",
        type: "post",
        async: false,
        data: {
            user_email: function() {
                return $("#user_email").val()
            }
        }
    }
},
                    pwd:{
                        required:true,
                        minlength: 6
                    },
                    cpwd:{
                        required:true,
                        equalTo: "#pwd"
                    },
                    gender:"required"
                },

                messages:{
                    usr_name:{
                    required: "Velg et brukernavn",
                    minlength: "Minimum 5 bokstaver",
                    remote: "Dette brukernavnet er opptatt"
                    },

                    full_name:"Skriv inn navnet ditt",
                    blog_name:"Velg en tittel til bloggen din",

                    user_email:{
                        required: "Fyll inn e-post adressen din",
                        email:"Dette er ikke en gyldig e-post adresse",
                        remote:"Denne e-posten finnes allerede"
                    },
                    pwd:{
                        required:"Velg passord",
                        minlength:"Passordet må ha 6 tall og bokstaver"
                    },
                    cpwd:{
                        required:"Gjenta passordet",
                        equalTo:"Passordene er ikke like"
                    },
                    gender:"Velg kjønn"
                },

                errorClass: "help-inline",
                errorElement: "span",
                highlight:function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('error');
                },
                unhighlight: function(element, errorClass, validClass) {
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').removeClass('error');
                    $(element).parents('.control-group').addClass('success');
                }

            });
```

Here's my checkmail.php (will sanitize once it works):

```
$duplicate = mysql_query("select count(*) as total from users where user_email='$user' ") or die(mysql_error());
    list($total) = mysql_fetch_row($duplicate);
        if ($total > 0)
        {
    $valid = 'false';
        } else {
    $valid = 'true';
        }
    echo $valid;
    exit;
```

It's not critical, as the form seems to submit, but i would hate leaving it like this when i am so close to what i want!

Hope this was understandable and i would really appreciate any help as ive read and tried everything google gave me!

Comment: can you show us the error? what is making it not work

Comment: It isnt an error as much as nothing is really happening. It simply wont trigger the validation events on first go. i have to re-trigger it by clicking the input again. then it works fine. it will however trigger on first go if the email is used.

Comment: have you tried using http://api.jquery.com/trigger/?

Comment: well, the validation triggers, as i move down the form. It's just the email and username rules that are bugging out. They require an additional click to trigger if the email or username returns true. on false it works as should.

Comment: made it work now, by setting async to true, and adding a line to the addclass lines, removing the success before adding class error. seems to work...
If anyone have better ways than that, please do share! =)

Answer (score 0):

I believe when it comes to AJAX in the form validation plugin, you'll need to use a callback and return the element.

```
onkeyup: function(element) {
    this.element(element);
}
```

The downside to this is that it will execute your AJAX on every keyup, so you'll want to perform some kind of check inside your callback. For example:

```
onkeyup: function(element) {
    if ( element.type == 'password' )
        this.element(element);
    else
        return true;
}
```